# VPN within a VM to allow for internet access on the host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I have a network connection (created under Networks and Sharing) that I use to connect to a customer's site.  But when I use this to connect to the site, I loose all access to the public internet, and can only access customer specific items.  I want to circumvent this issue by creating a VM and then utilizing the VM to connect to the network location and interact within the customer's domain, while leaving my host machine open to the internet.

I'm not extremely familiar with networking, but I have a few basic skills.  Please let me know if this is possible and what the correct procedures are.  I already have a VM created with VirtualBox, and both the host and guest are running Windows 7 x64.  I have created duplicate VPNs already, but can only connect successfully on the host machine.

Comment: I use to do this.  What VPN software do you use?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried running the virtual box and adapting to the vpn on your host and trying to reach the WAN on the VM, or vice versa? What is the VPN client? RSA? Citrix? Is this normative behavior for all the VPN users to be cut off from the WAN, or is this just your case?

Comment: I realized VPN was too broad.  I'm actually not using a VPN client to route the traffic, but instead I have a network location set up with the connection to their VPN server.  I have to connect using the network location which as far as I can tell, pushes all network traffic through to their location.  This leaves me without regular network access because I now only have access to the networks on their system.  I have edited the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

VPN software can be used to route either traffic destined for the remote network or all through the remote VPN concentrator. This is done by either keeping the default route through a physical interface or replacing it with a default route through the VPN. A similar thing is done for name resolution (DNS) queries. Usually there's one setting that you can use to choose between those two use cases.

You should acquire a basic knowlege of networking, especially of the terms I'm using above.